# Visual Studio .NET project is crashing after an update

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I updated my Visual Studio and I am working on a C# / .NET project. The program runs fine on a local machine but when I submit it online, the project crashed with this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

I am not sure why this has happened but I am guessing it's to do with the new version of Visual Studio and something I have to manually change in my project show it's running with the latest version. Anyone have any guesses?

Comment: You should change your title, your description and your tags.  This really has nothing to do with Visual Studio (you might mention that you recently updated it).  However, you should mention that it's an ASP.NET web application of some sort (I think).  Have you done what the error suggests you do.  It will temporarily make your site insecure (until you change it back), but it will show you where the error occurred, what the actual exception is, and what the faulting stack looks like.

Comment: It tells you that the real error is not displayed and that you need to change the web.config to get the real error. At that point it may become clear to you what is the problem. But please be more focused on the problem in the future, if you don't take the effort to understand the text expect that everyone else will take even less effort.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Visual Studio problem, it's problem inside your web site. To look at what happens change from `mode="Off"` to `mode="On"` and restart your web site:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```